# Use values instead of -1...1 for OpenGL drawing shapes?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

If I wanted to draw a plane in OpenGL, I would do something like the below:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
glEnd();
```

This draws a white plane that covers 50% of the canvas (from -0.5 to 0.5 on two axes). I want to use numbers instead, however. I don't want to use -1 to 1, but instead something like 0 to n, where n is the dimension of my canvas. For the above example, something like 250 to 750 on two axes on a 1000 pixel canvas rather than -0.5 to 0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the transformation matrices are for. In your case you'd set a ortho projection matrix with the limits as you desire. In your example case

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 1000, 0, 1000, -1, 1);
```

would set up a viewing volume so that the boundaries are at 0,0 for the lower left corner and 1000,1000 for the upper right.

Note that this (and the code you've given) use the old, deprecated fixed function pipeline. You should drop that in favour of a shader based approach.

Comment: +1 for explaining it, -1 for putting the shader recommendation as part of your answer (rather than a comment).

Comment: Cheers. I imagine `glOrtho` can also take `(-500,500,-500,500,...)` as arguments?

Comment: glOrtho takes floating point values as arguments. You can pass anything that fits into a float. OpenGL doesn't "think" it pixels. Everything happens in arbitrary units and only in the last step the numbers are transformed into pixel space.

Comment: @immibis: No, the shader recommendation *must* go there. The functions OP uses are terribly outdated and should not be used in any newly written code. And when doing it with shaders there are a lot of different ways the same result can be obtained.

Comment: @datenwolf Did you know that an extremely successful, $2B game was made using only OpenGL 1.1 features, plus multitexturing? What's the practical reason that the fixed function pipeline doesn't work?

Comment: @immibis: Yes, that was over 15 years ago (I presume you refer to either Quake 2 or Quake 3 Arena, and maybe HL1 using the GoldEngine (based on the Quake1 Engine)). The practical reason that you should not use the fixed function pipeline is that you'll be hard pressed to find some GPU in the wild that does not use shaders in one way or another. The fixed function pipeline is dead and burried… good riddance. Now new code using it should be written. Also using the programmable pipeline encourages to not use the immediate mode (which is a performance killer).

Comment: @immibis: So if you use the fixed function pipeline these days you're forcing the OpenGL driver to create a shader in-situ; immediate mode calls force the creation of in-situ vertex array and buffer object. Neither of this is efficient. In modern OpenGL (GL-3.3 core and later) all of this has been removed. So if you write code using the old, legacy stuff you can't trivially transition it into a program using modern OpenGL.

Comment: @datenwolf No, Minecraft. All modern drivers I'm aware of emulate the fixed function pipeline with shaders, so if all you want to do is throw some triangles on the screen with no fancy effects, you can still do that.

Comment: @immibis: But you shouldn't, because it makes it unneccesary hard to integrate new code with modern pipelines. For example my company makes realtime OCT systems and our software implements a graphics plugin framework. However only core profile OpenGL is supported. Now images somebody wrote some code that throws a few triangles at the screen that represent some physical manipulator that's been integrated with our OCT system. If this someone had written this with legacy OpenGL this could not be integrated with out software and had to be rewritten. Just say no to legacy OpenGL.